# Scala extends ServerSocket: Server is not bound yet error

Tags: scala, serversocket, extends

I'm a beginner in Scala, upfront apologies.
I'm trying to extend ServerSocket but I'm getting an unbound error. Any ideas?

```
class MyServer(port : Int) extends ServerSocket {
  ...
  var socket : Socket = this.accept()
```

This throws the error: Socket is not bound yet

```
class MyServer(port : Int) {
  var ss : ServerSocket = new ServerSocket(port)
  ...
  var socket : Socket = ss.accept()
```

This works.

Am I not passing in the port number to ServerSocket when I extend it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you're not passing the port number to the `ServerSocket` constructor when you extend it.

Here's how you do that:

```
class MyServer(port: Int) extends ServerSocket(port)
```